# Navigation/Section trouble

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a basic website for college but I have trouble doing the navigation sections that go drop down show in front of the section part since I had set it as position:fixed

How can I make the navigation in front of it the section but also keep the section fixed

Any type of way is open to try.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you just need z-index on navigation.

Place it as first child of  tag like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="navigation>...</div>
    <div class="container other-content"></div>
</body>
```

and since you gave it position: fixed; be sure to set z-index like this:

```
.navigation {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```